# Getting Count of the first list from joined two lists using Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code which joins two lists.

```
public List<Summary> GetSummary()
{
    List<Summary> summ = new List<Summary>();
    summ = (
        from xyz in (
            from list1 in GetList1()
            join list2 in GetList2() on list1.ID equals list2.ID
            select new { list1, list2 }
            )
        group xyz by new { xyz.list1.ID } into g
        select new Summary
        {
            ID = g.Key.ID,
            ItemCount = g.Sum(x => 1), //getting wrong count //g.Count() is also not working.
            Quantity = g.Sum(x => x.list1.Quantity),
            Weight = g.Sum(x => x.list2.Weight),
            Time = TimeSpan.FromHours(Convert.ToDouble(g.Sum(x => x.list1.Time))).ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss"),
        }
            ).ToList();
    return summ;
}
```

I want to get the count of the first list (List1) but I am getting wrong count (in multiples). Eg. If the item count is 6 then I am getting the result as 36.

Comment: Are you sure there are no duplicate ids in either list?

Comment: Yes.. No duplicates. The second list is having only ID and Weight fields.

Comment: And items in the first list are also unique

Comment: Yes. ID is alone common for the lists.

Comment: post some sample data, I tried to reproduce and if the ids are unique in each list, `ItemCount` will be 1. Here is the fiddle so you can see for yourself : https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZyJqOv

Comment: If your ids are not unique the join syntax will match each id in the first list with each id in the second list, so if the ids were to be [1,1,1] and [1, 1] you would get an item count of 6

Comment: What is the relationship between the tables? If there are no dups what is the idea behind `g.Sum(x => x.list1.Quantity)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have re-wrote the query. Try below. First join the collections and get the items you need. Then you can perform the group on that will prevent duplications.

```
 public List<Summary> GetSummary()
        {
            List<Summary> summ = new List<Summary>();
            summ = (
                        from list1 in GetList1()
                        join list2 in GetList2() on list1.ID equals list2.ID
                        select new
                        {
                            ID = list1.ID,
                            Quantity = list1.Quantity,
                            Weight = list2.Weight,
                            Time = list1.Time
                        }
                        into list
                        group list by new { list.ID } into g
                        select new Summary
                        {
                            ID = g.Key.ID,
                            ItemCount = g.Count(),
                            Quantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
                            Weight = g.Sum(x => x.Weight),
                            Time = TimeSpan.FromHours(Convert.ToDouble(g.Sum(x => x.Time))).ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss"),
                        }
                      ).ToList();

            return summ;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I am still getting count duplication. Hence, Checking all my codes internally. Will update you once done.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? I just used GroupJoin on ID property and used the same logic as yours.

```
var summ = GetList1().GroupJoin(GetList2(), l1 => l1.ID, l2 => l2.ID, 
            (l, g) => new Summary 
            { 
                ID = l.ID, 
                ItemCount = g.Count(), 
                Quantity = l.Quantity,
                Weight = g.Sum(x => x.Weight),
                Time = TimeSpan.FromHours(Convert.ToDouble(g.Sum(x => x.Time))).ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss"),
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't get some of the fields. Ex. Quantity, Time comes from list1, and weight comes from list2.

Comment: access the fields by "l." coming from list1 and by "g." coming from list2.